# App crashing in Ipad 3rd Generation , but working fine in ipad 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My App is crashing in Ipad 3rd Generation but working fine in my ipad 2 , in ipad 3rd Gen its saying "Memory Warning". My app is in ARC .The console log is like below. I googled few times about this , in one of the post they suggested to change the plist name , i am wired but tried, no change.Please help me.Thank you

```
2013-04-17 13:21:42 +0000 searchd Could not open updates file for com.apple.MobileSMS SMSSearch

2013-04-17 13:21:42 +0000 searchd Finished getting 33 applications, took 0.048442 seconds
2013-04-17 13:21:43 +0000 searchd Indexed all records in 0.28s
2013-04-17 13:22:09 +0000 SpringBoard could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.OneandoLLC.MyApp-14C1F156-4461-410E-93CE-4FE55B75B86D'
2013-04-17 13:22:14 +0000 lsd Attempting to store identifiers file
2013-04-17 13:22:14 +0000 lsd updating identifier store

2013-04-17 13:22:27 +0000 SpringBoard Memory level is not normal. Pending auto-relaunch of 'com.facebook.Facebook' until it is.
2013-04-17 13:22:27 +0000 backboardd Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x7974]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
2013-04-17 13:22:27 +0000 backboardd Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mybusinessapp.JPOP[0x22fc]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
2013-04-17 13:22:27 +0000 backboardd Application 'UIKitApplication:com.mybusinessapp.dssapp[0x11db]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
2013-04-17 13:22:27 +0000 backboardd Application 'UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Facebook[0xbf29]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
2013-04-17 13:22:28 +0000 My App Received memory warning.
2013-04-17 13:22:31 +0000 backboardd -[BKSystemAppSentinel lock_bootstrapEmbedded] Found running system app (com.apple.SpringBoard, pid 66). Attempting to stop it...
2013-04-17 13:22:32 +0000 SpringBoard lockdown says we've previously registered: [0], state is 0
2013-04-17 13:22:32 +0000 SpringBoard lockdown says the device is: [Activated], state is 3
2013-04-17 13:22:32 +0000 SpringBoard ERROR: _xpc_handle_outgoing_request error: Connection invalid
2013-04-17 13:22:32 +0000 backboardd Telling the system app that it can start immediately
2013-04-17 13:22:38 +0000 SpringBoard BTM: attaching to BTServer
2013-04-17 13:22:39 +0000 assistant_service the local store doesn't allow tasks and we have no default calendar :(
2013-04-17 13:22:39 +0000 SpringBoard WiFi picker plugin initialized
2013-04-17 13:22:39 +0000 SpringBoard SIMToolkit plugin for SpringBoard initialized.
2013-04-17 13:22:39 +0000 SpringBoard SMS Plugin initialized.
2013-04-17 13:22:42 +0000 itunesstored iTunes Store environment is: ST11
2013-04-17 13:22:49 +0000 assistant_service the local store doesn't allow tasks and we have no default calendar :(
```

Comment: try unisntalling the app, and doing a "clean"

Comment: Nothing much to go on here. Have you tried running in a debugger? Have you tried forcing a memory warning in the Simulator?

Comment: @StephenDarlington Hi,when i am running the app in simulator then its working fine, no memory warnings in the console, problem is with ipad 3rd Gen only.Got my point.

Comment: In the Simulator there's a menu item where you can force a memory warning. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

you are using ARC but ARC is not provide any guarantee related to memory crash,compiler have automatically leave reference when resource is free but if any resources use in whole navigation flow then it can not leave reference, if your app have memory crashes, then check your app on Instruments tool, specially focus on dirty size section on instrument tool.